# Red border remains on the TextBox even after the data input is valid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing an app using WPF, WPF Application Framework and MahApps.Metro. I have validation enabled for a data entry window like this:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="FinancePlus.Presentations.Views.CustomerView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="526"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             xmlns:presentation="clr-namespace:System.Waf.Presentation;assembly=WpfApplicationFramework"
             presentation:ValidationHelper.IsEnabled="true" presentation:ValidationHelper.IsValid="{Binding IsValid, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
             Title="Customer Editor">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>            
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Green.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>


        </ResourceDictionary>


    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Customer}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <GroupBox Header="Personal Information" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="Title:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23"  Margin="3" Name="titleTextBox" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="120" />
                    <Label Content="Full Name:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23"  Margin="3" Name="fullNameTextBox" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=FullName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="120" />
                    <Label Content="Name With Initials:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23"  Margin="4" Name="nameWithInitialsTextBox" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=NameWithInitials, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="120" />
                    <Label Content="Civil Status:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"  Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="CivilStatus" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="23"  
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="3" Name="civilStatusComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <Label Content="Date Of Birth:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"  Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="25"  Margin="3" Name="dateOfBirthDatePicker" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="115" />                    
                    <Label Content="Id Number:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"  Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Height="23"  Margin="3" Name="idNumberTextBox" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=IdNumber, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="120" />                    
                    <Label Content="Profession:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"  Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Height="23"  Margin="3" Name="professionTextBox" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=Profession, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="120" />                    
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>

..... More code.
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Which looks nice. The trouble is even when I enter valid values for a `TextBox` a red border remains. Like you can see in the title and full name `TextBox`es here. How do I remove this residue red border? Where is it coming from?

[image]

Comment: how is your viewmodel implemented? Especially the properties (Title, FullName).

Comment: Have you sorted this issue? I am having a similar problem. Also, could you show how you implement the error checking?

Comment: I've also come across this issue, no idea how to fix it. It also appears suddenly, it doesn't seem to be anything to do with property changed notification. And the Validation.HasErrors and Validation.Errors attached properties show that there are no errors on the control. Its like the code that put those adorners in the layer has been reset without removing them.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this before, when it happened to me I had to perform a data change during `initialize` and `ContentRendered`. Cause I had the items actually bound.

Another thing I saw awhile ago on Stack Overflow was an issue that happened here that also caused something similar.

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="converter" />
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Border 
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Mode=OneWay, Path=AdornedElement.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource converter}}">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
                </Border>
             </DockPanel>
         </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

That was my encounter, if that doesn't help I'll attempt to recreate the issue and fix as well. See if I can help you out a little better then describing how I fixed it. But hopefully one of those two suggestions helps you out.

Just let me know, hope it helps.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out a way to stop this happening when you update viewmodel data during OnInitialize?