# TextBox Validation doesn't disappear after satisfying the expression in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm creating a `WPF` application, using `Metro` styling. Within my app, I use `Regex` `regular expressions` for my `properties` to use for `validation`. This seemed quite straight forward and easy to use.

But, I come across a strange behavior. When using the `validation`, some of the `textbox's` and fields within the `UserControl` don't seem to disappear, even though the expression has been matched. The following picture shows how it is responding;

[image]

Within my `UserControl`, I call a `resource` like the following;

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Styling\ValidationStyle.xaml"/>
```

This problem only seems to occur when I have the use of the `visibility` property within my fields. It just doesn't seem to notify the `UI` that the validation has been matched. Also, if I swap `Tabs` for example, it removes the red line altogether, but that's not idea having the user to swap tabs.

Rather then using the `ResourceDictionary` I tried to call the style within the textbox itself like so;

```
Style="{StaticResource myErrorTemplate}"
```

But when doing so, it doesn't implement the Metro style validation, of having a triangle in the top corner but instead uses the `*` like in the `datepicker`.

Any ideas how this could be solved? Obviously, if a new user was to use this, they would get confused and therefore I am trying to prevent that.

Here a link with my code one; [Code](https://gist.github.com/gregorybmclub/e3aeb7ccefe3e1765d48)

Any help is much appreciated, Cheers :).

Comment: This same issue is described in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377474/red-border-remains-on-the-textbox-even-after-the-data-input-is-valid

Comment: Hi,

Can you share how the code how do you implement the validation you have? I'm also trying to implement validation in my project but mahapps doesn't have much code for reference.

Thanks