# WPF MVVM Input Validation Using WAF Framework

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, mahapps.metro, waf-framework-c#

I am writing an application using WPF, MahApps and WAF (WPF Application Framework). WAF doesn't seem to have any good examples of how to use their validation using ValidationHelper. A simple example with a TextBox validating for no input OnPropertyChanged would have been of great help.

A very good match to what I am doing is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377474/red-border-remains-on-the-textbox-even-after-the-data-input-is-valid), but it is lacking most of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BookLibrary sample application](http://waf.codeplex.com) shows how the ValidationHelper can be used.

```
BookListView.xaml:    

waf:ValidationHelper.IsEnabled="true" 
waf:ValidationHelper.IsValid="{Binding IsValid, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

The class tracks WPF Validation Errors and updates the IsValid property which is bound to the ViewModel in the sample above. This way the ViewModel can react on an invalid View.